# Working outside of application context Flask Celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I will preface with that I know there are a few solutions for this issue floating around, though none of them follow this guide [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) and don't seem to answer my question.

I am receiving this error from my Celery app in Flask.

```
[2021-11-23 22:50:01,469: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task smartful_versioning_flask.test_celery_task[6dda4a4b-cf64-4fdc-8317-237dca9ad31b] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('Working outside of application context.\n\nThis typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed\nto interface with the current application object in some way. To solve\nthis, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the\ndocumentation for more information.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_versioning_flask.py", line 21, in test_celery_task
    return jsonify({"something": "something"})
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 336, in jsonify
    if current_app.config["JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR"] or current_app.debug:
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 422, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "/var/smartful_flask/smartful_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 47, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
**RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.**

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

After much troubleshooting, I am at a complete loss. Where does one pass in app context as referenced in the exception?

```
     from flask import Flask, jsonify
     from celery import Celery
     
     app = Flask(__name__)
     app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
     app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
     
     celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
     celery.conf.update(app.config)
     
     @celery.task
     def test_celery_task():
         return jsonify({"something": "something"})
     
     @app.route("/web/start/backend", methods=['POST'])
     def start_task():
         task = test_celery_task.apply_async()
         return task.id
     
     @app.route("/web/check-status/backend/<task_id>", methods=['GET'])
     def check_task(task_id):
         task = test_celery_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
     
         if task.state == 'PENDING':
             return jsonify({
                 "task": task_id,
                 "state": task.state,
                 "data": None,
                 "complete": False,
                 "error": False
             })
         elif task.state == 'SUCCESS':
             print(task.info)
         else:
             print(task.state)
     
         return "task.info"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

As expected here with this traceback, the task will fail and never return from the backend.  I am using Ngnix, wsgi, Supervisor to serve this - though the same issue exists with or without supervisor spawning the workers.

I am sure it is something silly and trivial that I am overlooking, though as per usual - too blind to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the fix here and am notating it for others with a similar situation.  This has to do with the working directory that supervisor is using.

I went into the directory of my flask app and spawned a single worker manually:

```
# smartful_venv/bin/celery --app=smartful_versioning_flask.celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG
```

I ran my flask app as seen in the question, my return prints successfully.  My situation is likely Supervisor does not have access to the working directory which I am using. It is not explicitly stated however this issue is not discussed in supervisor docs really, though supervisor reports it is being run as root - it lies!

### Edit to add:

In another task, I needed to add `with app.app_context():` before doing anything. That is odd to me, but it works. If anyone has an explanation as to why app context exists only after the with, it might lead to a healthy discussion.